# Can i anyone tell the solution how to write this formatted data using C

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have to write a binary data that i recv from the server into a binary file so i wrote the following function:-

```
int WriteToDataFile1(char buf[])
{
    char szDate[12];
    char szTime[12];
    char buf_buff[2500];
    _strdate( szDate );
    _strtime( szTime );
    memset(buf_buf, 0, sizeof(buf_buff));
    FILE* log = fopen(BufferFilePath11, "a+");
    if (log == NULL)
        return -1;
    fwrite(buf,1,135,log); //working fine
    fclose(log);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting two problems:-
1)I have to write the binary data like DATE::TIME::DATA IS::DATA.
I am not able to do like the following:-

```
sprintf(buf_buf,"%s::%s::DATA IS::", szDate, szTime,buf);
```

As sprintf will terminate the when it encounters the null character in the "buf".
There is always 135byte data from server but sometimes there is null character at 17th byte or some other byte so sprintf will terminate the string there i will not write the complete binary data.
My second problem is with fwrite my data is one line even when 2nd time WriteToDataFile1() function whereas i should write in the 2nd line
Can i anyone tell the solution.

Comment: Please format your source code in a way that's readable.

Comment: If you want to format your output like that, then just write it as a text file, why write it in binary mode? You get no benefits.

Comment: Can i anyone format this question, my eyes are zig-zagging

Comment: Are you concerned with the endian format of the data? Using `fwrite()` like that leads me to believe no...

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem (unable to use sprintf) is not a problem, it's working as intended. You may not use sprintf to place binary data into your buffer. You'll need to place the data there another way (perhaps using memcpy).

As to your second problem, the data is "one line" -- you stated you're writing a binary file; there are zero lines. If you want to write a line termination character (\n, \r, etc) then you can fwrite that out after the other data you've written.

Comment: sir how to write data after DATE:TIME,i want the data time should be written first followed by the binary data

Comment: sir how to write data after DATE:TIME,i want the data time should be written first followed by the binary data

Comment: To send both ascii and binary data out, I would recommend using fprintf() for the ascii, then fwrite() for the binary. You can go back and forth between them.

Comment: i somehow managed this now i am facing the problem that i added \n also but then also my data gets written in the same line the second time i call the function to write,can u also please also give up a pseudo code for switching between fprintf and fwrite

Comment: `fprintf(log, "%s::%s::DATA IS::", szDate, szTime); fwrite(buf, 1, 135, log); fprintf(log, "\n");` should do it. You might replace the last fprintf with `fprintf(log, "\r\n");`.

Comment: Sir i need a bit more help,can i post here my code break at a point.